# Complicated logic that Nodejs is not good at

Tags: node.js

I've heard that nodejs is not good for applications that apply complicated logic. Can I get an example of this?

I've also heard the same thing about cpu intensive tasks. Can I get a basic example of this too?

Comment: Rumours and hearsay, unless you provide a reliable source.

Comment: any tool is only as good as its user. nowadays it is always more about the architecture than the language, The biggest drawback of nodejs is the fact that it is still young and hence kinda loose. Guidelines can be ambiguous and too blur to follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really correct. Javascript is perfect for complex logic. But javascript is single threaded. This means that lets say you write a server in "metacode".

```
var httpServer = require('http');
httpServer.onRequest(respond); 

function respond(requestContext) {
  thread.sleep(2000) // or do some heavy calculations which takes while
                     // like sorting array with 100000000000 elements
  sendResponse();
};
```

This means that your server will not serve other clients at all, since whole application (which have only single thread) is busy. 
So it is not about complex logic. It is about heavy computations.

Comment: Very true. Node.js is a perfect tool for complex I/O-bound logic, but it's not a good choice for CPU-bound tasks.